# Get Main form's listbox from an another class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It is not a duplicate, at least i don't think so.

I have a mainform with a `listbox` (List of applications)  and i want to do different things with differents buttons.

I would like to have a public class with differents instances to simplify my code.

The thing is I can't access to my listbox from this class. And i can't do the usual way " `Form1 form = new Form1();` " , I want my main form to continue do things besides.

Heres a part of my **Code** to get you the idea:

```
    public class Getwindow
    {
        public string Check { get; set; }

            public void Checkwindow()
           {  foreach (string App in Form1.ListBox1) //doesn't work 
//it says Form1 does not contain a definition for "ListBox1"
            {if (App.Contains(Check)
                             {return true;}
             }
            public void maxwindow()
           { //otherscode here   }

    }
```

And on my **MainForm**:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
     GetWindows App1 = new GetWindows();
     GetWindows App2 = new GetWindows();

     public string Check { get; set; }

      private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {  App1.Check = nameofapp1
               App2.Check = nameofapp2 
               [...]
             }
     private void Checkapp1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            { 
    App1.checkwindow(); 
            }
     private void Getapp()
        {//void to get all app opens and put it on the listbox}
    }
```

I really don't manage to get the value from the `form`. I tried to put all the methods in my mainform and do things like `Form1 App1 = new Form1()` but I get exceptions error on some methods (no idea why though ). But i would prefer call my `listbox` from the class.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried accepting a `ListBox` type as a parameter in your `GetWindows()` method (e.g. `GetWindows(ListBox sender) { ... }`)? Then when you call it from the form, you can pass the `ListBox` (from the form itself) to the method. This will allow you to access the actual form's `ListBox1`

Comment: What is your `GetWindows()` method actually used for? What are you looking to do with the data from the `ListBox1`?

Comment: Yes that's actually clever. I m very new on c#.. i will dot that !! 
Listbox1 Data is the list of the opened application on windows, getwindow help me to open them dynamically  (and i send click and keyboard shortcut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just pass to the method everything it needs:

```
public void Checkwindow(ListBox listBox)
{
   //listBox.Items or whatever you want to do.
}
```

Also add to the class:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

In form:

```
App1.checkwindow(ListBox1);
```

### Better Approach:

For me a better approach would be to pass a `List<string>` from `Form1` to the method `Checkwindow()`. You should not have your classes tied to controls, but to data. Like this in `Form1`:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
{
    data.Add(item.ToString());
}

App1.checkwindow(data);
```

And in your class:

```
public void Checkwindow(List<string> data)
{
    foreach (string str in data)
    {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

This way if you change your `ListBox` to a `ComboBox` for some reason, you just change how you pass the data and not your "Business Logic" classes.

Comment: Good idea with wrapping up a list of arguments, to aid with reusable code :)

Comment: Ok i will pass my data from my listbox to a list<string> ! thank you for the advice!